# cache-control key set in s3 and present in response header, but images are not caching

Tags: amazon-s3, caching, amazon-cloudfront, rails-activestorage

I set cache-control key on bucket with this value: public, max-age=86400. This shows up in the response header, but the images are not being cached. Images are coming back with 200. I'm using active storage, s3, and CloudFront.

/// response header below ///

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="xhbtr_ba6c7e14-cab0-44c2-8701-e48aa75ab3f7_w1200.jpg"; filename*=UTF-8''xhbtr_ba6c7e14-cab0-44c2-8701-e48aa75ab3f7_w1200.jpg
Content-Length: 1444501
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2020 15:15:21 GMT
ETag: "18c45e75803b2a82c0a85dc4dde7bba4"
Last-Modified: Mon, 14 Sep 2020 14:00:44 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2: /6ynYC2FE4QwOaVJe1uJOBeCsJhfKFzNbMu+X7r0L5pRyax2JoxzJ5qoyO0Sb7dr09yFxZYj5/iE=
x-amz-request-id: 415DC4198F2ED5F1
```

Comment: Please clarify how and where you determine that the images are not cached.

Comment: Images are coming back with 200, not 304.

Answer (score 0):

```
Server: AmazonS3
```

You are querying S3. S3 has no cache. (The `cache-control` directive is meant for the client, not the server.)

What you probably want is to use Cloudfront as an edge cache. Cloudfront loosely adheres on the cache-control directive for edge caching (depending on how you configure it). Since you mention Cloudfront in your question, I assume you have already set it up. So instead of calling the S3 URL, use the URL you’ve set up in the Cloudfront configuration.